# IBM.Data.DB2 throws Exception in Azure WebJob

Tags: azure, db2, ibm-cloud, azure-webjobs

I have a webjob project that uses IBM.Data.DB2 that works locally, but fails in azure:

[Exception: unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbuFi.png)

App.config providers:
`<providers> <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" /> <provider invariantName="IBM.Data.DB2" type="IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework.DB2ProviderServices, IBM.Data.DB2.EntityFramework, Version=10.5.5.6, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208" /> </providers> </entityFramework> <system.data> <DbProviderFactories> <!-- NOTE: Need to comment out this line when testing locally, uncomment when deploying to Azure app service --> <add name="IBM DB2 .NET Data Provider" invariant="IBM.Data.DB2" description="IBM DB2 Data Provider for .NET Framework 4.0" type="IBM.Data.DB2.DB2Factory, IBM.Data.DB2, Version=9.7.4.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7c307b91aa13d208" /> </DbProviderFactories> </system.data>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to load DLL 'db2app64.dll'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57327791/unable-to-load-dll-db2app64-dll/68290644#68290644)

Comment: [Unable to load DLL 'db2app.dll - IBM Support](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000060GI0RCAW/unable-to-load-dll-db2appdll?language=en_US) and [Server fails to start with "The program can't start because DB2APP64.dll is missing from your computer"](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/server-fails-start-program-cant-start-because-db2app64dll-missing-your-computer)